# Can you propagate changes to multiple projects via GDM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

If I'm describing and managing the resources in my GCP projects via GDM (Google Deployment Manager), is it possible to propagate a change to multiple Google Cloud projects via GDM (Google Deployment Manager)?

Specifically, I'm looking at defining a BigQuery schema (set of datasets & tables) via GDM, and then syncing this schema across numerous projects (each of which will have their own BigQuery db). So ideally if I make a schema update like adding a column to a table, I only need to update a single "deployment" for the schema change to propagate to all the relevant projects.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Deployment Manager allows for actions to be propagated within the project. That being said, to make changes through multiple projects, you have to make a call per project. Consequently, the schema changes produced on one project will not be reproduced on BigQuery tables found in other projects.